# Resource management for NodeJS

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, is there a concept similar to Spring Application Container or JEE Application Container where resources can be configured and shared among application components.

Such resources are:

- Database connection
- Redis connection
- AMQP connection
  ...

where as these connections must/should be open for a long time. It's a bad practice to open/close for each HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, each module is cached globally so when you `require()` or `import()` a module it is the same one every time.

So when your data module consumes a redis or db module and open a connection, it will remain open until you close it, and that same connection may be available for the other modules that import your data module.

Some database/messaging modules provide connection pooling for you.   In fact you should be able to find such modules on npmjs.com or node-modules.com and not have to create your own pooling solution for common systems.